# Flexbox not working in Safari but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, safari, flexbox

HTML code:

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 1</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec 
    arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel 
    semper. Sed a risus purus.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 2</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 3</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 4</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 5</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 6</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec 
    arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel 
    semper. Sed a risus purus.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 1</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec 
    arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel 
    semper. Sed a risus purus.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 2</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 3</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 4</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 5</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis.</p>
        </div>
    </div><div class="box odd">
        <div class="box-title">TITLE 6</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
    Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
    Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec 
    arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel 
    semper. Sed a risus purus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;
    list-style: none;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.box {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.box.odd {max-width: 16.66%;}
.box.even {max-width: 25%;}
.box.side-block {margin: 10px 0; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.box.side-block .box-title {background-color: #70E070;}
.box.side-block .box-content {padding: 0 8px 8px;}
.box.side-block .box-content p {margin-bottom: 0;}
.box .box-title {background-color: #FF4A4A; color: #fff; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;}
.box.odd .box-title {background-color: #4F8DFF;}
.box.even .box-title {background-color: #FF4A4A;}
.box .box-content {text-align: left;}
```

Here is the code example in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxzmZr

Check in Chrome/Firefox then check in Safari. In Chrome/Firefox, I see all the 6 boxes aligned (like I want) but in Safari one box show per line.

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with .box max-width. I just changed it to width and all worked fine.